# Any way for get_next_post() to use the actual post order instead of publish order?

Tags: posts, permalinks, get-posts, order

I'm currently using get_next_post() and get_previous_post() to get their ID so that I can permalink my next/previous buttons for a custom post type. I'm also using a wordpress plugin called "Anything Order" to be able to reorder them however I want.

Problem is, no matter the order I give them, get_next_post() and get_previous_post() will ALWAYS fetch the adjacent posts depending on their PUBLISHED date. It completely ignores the actual order of the posts.

Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: Hello ODelorme - welcome to the WordPress Development community! The `post` post-type does not natively support `page-attributes` which is the feature that supplies ordering. As such, however this "Anything Order" plugin is ordering your posts is not native functionality of WordPress; thus your question is regarding 3rd-party plugin functionality which is considered "off-topic" for our community. It would be best asked in the official support channels for the plugin. Please read the [ask] and [on-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) sections of our [help] for more info.

Comment: If you can figure out _how_ the "Anything Order" plugin is implementing it's ordering functionality and share that information in your question, it may be enough to bring your question back on topic.

Comment: Found a solution: http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress

Amazing plug-in for Wordpress if anyone's interested !